# Sending a lot of data in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am currently developping an app, that lets users send sensor data to an [OSC receiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control) via UDP, nothing malicious, the user is in full control of everything.

When the user enables sending of data, every sensor change event triggers the dispatch of a packet, if the user enables this sensor and axis for transmission.

This possibly leads to a lot of data to send, e.g. if the user wants to control the synthesizer with a lot of parameters from his mobile phone (think of drum sounds triggered by jumping around while your orientation in space changes the timbre).

I have now tested the following approaches, but each one has a downside and/or crash on different Android versions:

1. Use `AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>` and send the data in `doInBackground(String... strings)`. The downside to this approach is a possible `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` in Android 2.3.3, because this may create too many threads.
2. Use `IntentService` and send the data `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`. The downside to this approach is a slow and unresponsive UI in Android 2.3.3.
3. Use a bound `Service` and send data on an exposed function of the service. This works like a charm on Android 2.3.3, but crashes on Android 4.4.4 with a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

What other possibilities are there? Will running an `AsyncTask<>` in the bound `Service` not run into any of the two exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a single Thread rather than an AsyncTask?  With an event loop in it which waits for data to be posted to it, then sends the data to the server?  Basically its an AsyncTask that never ends and sleeps until data is posted to it.  This thread can be owned by an Activity or Service, whichever makes sense for you.

As an aside, this app of yours will kill your battery.  But I suspect you know that and are ok with it.

Comment: I used a custom `HandlerThread` and a custom `Handler` class for that. One small follow-up: "killing" the battery means "draining" in that context, right?

Comment: Yes.  Frequent radio usage sending data will drain a lot of battery.  As in a full charge may go in a few hours, depending on how big a battery their device has.  If your app will still work, you may want to batch data and send it every few minutes instead.

Comment: Draining is OK in that case, but "killing" batteries can have the meaning of destroying the battery. Collecting and sending data later is not an option, as the app should be used for live controlling of software synthesizers.

Comment: THen you should be fine.  TO be clear, there won't be any more damage to the battery than would be caused by using the battery normally.  It just means that you'll have to plug it in sooner, and that you'll have more recharge cycles on it (which can reduce the battery lifespan slightly, but we're not talking about it suddenly dieing or exploding here).